# Android retrieving data with two line listview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a Android and Firebase beginner, I want to retrieve data from Firebase, but I hope my question and answer can in the same block, how can I do?

This is my interface:

[image]

This is my firebase structure:

[image]

This is my code:

```
private ArrayList<DB_Question> list=new ArrayList<>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterQ = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
            android.R.id.text1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapterQ);

    DatabaseReference reference_contacts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("question");
    reference_contacts.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            adapterQ.clear();
            for(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                adapterQ.add(ds.child("Que").getValue().toString());
                adapterQ.add(ds.child("Ans").getValue().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain question more clearly. and post your data structure of firebase

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can design your listview layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 ...
 ...>
 <TextView
   //for question/>
 <TextView
   //for answer/>
 </Linearlayout>
```

Add forgot password and mail to swlabgroup2@gmail.com textviews in mainActivity with listview .
And if you have lot of questions and answers I will recommend you to use Recycler View instead of ListView.